# List groupings repeating values when document library is added to page

Tags: list, document-library, custom, grouping

I have a custom list displayed on a page. In the view for this list has a filter and a grouping. When I add a document library to the page, the groupings display all of the filtered items under each grouping. If the Document library is first on the page, the groupings work as expected. If I place the List first, the groupings are messed up again. Is this a known issue? Is there a workaround or fix?

Answer (score 1):

this is a grouping bug , you need to enable server side rendering on your webpart

this is under :edit webpart/miscellaneous/server render

mark the checkbox and save, that should fix the issue

Comment: Thank You. Server Render did help. However, I did do some customization with JSlink. That is not working now.

Comment: Yikes !  
welcome to a SP SinkHole 
server side rendering disables all Client side rendering (js link) 
maybe you can do some script edition and add some CSS or JavaScript to help you